# SignalR .NET 6 Client Not adding handler

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-6.0

So, I am trying to do a SIMPLE task with SignalR right now. Basically, I have a console app that will have .NET SignalR client, and a .NET 6 Web API with SignalR server.

I am just trying to do a simple flow:

1. Client sends request to SignalR Hub
2. Hub processes request, and returns data back to .NET client

I have no user interaction at all, that's why I'm not using JS, as this will not be in the browser.

Here is my current setup **for the SignalR Server**

`OnPremAgentClientHub` in Web API:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace HttpLongPollingServer.Hubs
{
    public sealed class OnPremClientHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task GetOnPremAgentStatus(string clientIp)
        {
            bool isReachable = OnPremAgentData.IsAgentPingable(clientIp)
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("OnPremAgentStatusReceived", isReachable);
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant code from `Program.cs` in Web API for SignalR setup:

```
app.MapHub<OnPremClientHub>("/clienthub", options => 
    {
        options.Transports = HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
    });
```

Yes, I want to force HTTP Long polling.

Here is my setup in the console app for **SignalR client**

`Program.cs`

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:7184/clienthub")
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
            // This will set ALL logging to Debug level
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
        })
    .Build();

await hubConnection.StartAsync();



await LongPollingTest.TestHttpSignalRLongPolling(hubConnection);
```

The `TestHttpSignalRLongPolling` that calls the SignalR Hub methods:

```
public static async Task TestHttpSignalRLongPolling(HubConnection hubConnection) 
        {
            await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("GetOnPremAgentStatus", arg1: "192.168.19.128");

            hubConnection.On("OnPremAgentStatusReceived", (bool isReachable) => {
                if (isReachable)
                    Console.WriteLine("Agent is reachable");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Agent is not reachable");
            });
        }
```

Now, I can get the client to invoke the `GetOnPremAgentStatus`. However, when the client goes to do the `hubConnection.On()...` I get the following `Warning` and `Error`

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[14]
> Failed to find handler for 'OnPremAgentStatusReceived' method.
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[57]
> Failed to bind arguments received in invocation '(null)' of 'OnPremAgentStatusReceived'.
> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Invocation provides 1 argument(s) but target expects 0.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.BindTypes(Utf8JsonReader& reader, IReadOnlyList`1 paramTypes)

I'm banging my head against a wall. I feel it's something simple I'm missing, I just don't know what it is.

Any tips or help is appreciated!

Comment: Try this client code, I have added an option for client connection to use LongPolling. This might help.  var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:7184/clienthub", opt => { opt.Transports = Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.LongPolling;})
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
            // This will set ALL logging to Debug level
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
        })
    .Build();

Comment: opt.Transports => Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.LongPolling;

Comment: Thanks, @ChinmayT for taking the time to respond. But, I found my issue. I will post my findings as the answer. 

Although, I did add the `Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.LongPolling` option to my client for consistency.

Comment: Just flip the order of the InvokeAsync and On("OnPremAgentStatusReceived"). You're invoking the method on the client before the callback is registered.

Comment: Yes, @davidfowl. Thank you for the response. That was my solution, that I found out. I posted it as my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so the answer was staring me straight in the face in the Microsoft docs. The problem was that I was trying to call a callback on an unregistred handler that is located in my Server Hub in my client code. The fix was easy. I simply moved my `connection.On` to `Program.cs` after making my Hub Connection, but before starting the connection.

Updated `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using HttpLongPollingClientConsole;

ServiceProvider service = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging((loggingBuilder) => loggingBuilder
    .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug)
    .AddConsole()
    .AddDebug())
    .BuildServiceProvider();

var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:7184/clienthub", options => 
    {
        options.Transports = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
            // This will set ALL logging to Debug level
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
        })
    .Build();

// Register the handler here!! 
hubConnection.On<bool>("OnPremAgentStatusReceived", (isReachable) => {
    if (isReachable)
        Console.WriteLine("Agent is reachable");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Agent is not reachable");
});

hubConnection.StartAsync().Wait();

await LongPollingTest.TestHttpSignalRLongPolling(hubConnection);

Console.ReadKey();
```

This is explained in [the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#call-client-methods-from-hub) very well.

Now, from my Debug output of the SignalR client I can see the Handler being registered properly.

> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[40]
> Registering handler for client method 'OnPremAgentStatusReceived'.